# How to disable controls until a condition is met?

Tags: c#, winforms, loops

Currently in my program in about 10 control event handlers I have this code:

```
        if (!mapLoaded)
            return;
```

When I load a map through the open file dialog I set mapLoaded to true. Another way to do this would be to just disable all the controls for startup and after loading a map to enable all the controls. Unfortunately there are 30+ controls and this is just 30 lines of..

```
a.Enabled = true;
b.Enabled = true;
c.Enabled = true;
```

I can't really do a foreach loop through this.Controls either because some of the controls are menustrip items, toolstrip items, panel items, scrollbars, splitters, et cetera and that loop doesn't cover that.

Ideally there would be a way to set every control's enabled property to true in a single and simple loop but I'm not sure of how to do that. Any ideas SO?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Use data binding:**

1. Change `mapLoaded` into a property that notifies observers when its value has changed...

   ```
   public bool MapLoaded
   {
       get
       {
           return mapLoaded;
       }
       set
       {
           if (value != mapLoaded)
           {
               mapLoaded = value;
               MapLoadedChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
           }
       }
   }
   private bool mapLoaded;

   public event EventHandler MapLoadedChanged = delegate {};
   // ^ or implement INotifyPropertyChanged instead
   ```
2. Data-bind your controls' `Enabled` property to `MapLoaded`. You can set up the data bindings either using the Windows Forms designer, or using code, e.g. right after `InitializeComponent();`:

   ```
   a.DataBindings.Add("Enabled", this, "MapLoaded");
   b.DataBindings.Add("Enabled", this, "MapLoaded");
   c.DataBindings.Add("Enabled", this, "MapLoaded");
   ```

Comment: You said you could set up data bindings using the Windows Forms designer. Where is the option for that? I do not see a Bindings or DataBindings property listed in the properties windows when selecting controls.

Comment: @John, this usually involves four steps (in VS2010): **1.** Add a new object data source to the project; in this case, you'd add the `Form` class itself as a data source. You might have to compile the project first so that the `Form` class is visible in the *Add Data Source* wizard. **2.** Add a `BindingSource` component to your Form and select the `Form` object data source for it. **3.** In the `Form`'s constructor, set `formBindingSource.DataSource = this;`. **4.** Use the *Advanced Bindings* wizard in any control's *Properties* to define data bindings.

Answer (score 2):

How about changing your opening strategy, have a new form that let's your user load a map, and the simply not load your main form until one has been loaded?

Comment: This is a decent suggestion but I prefer stakx's solution. Upvoted nonetheless.